# Create an array from values in key/value object?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of different exercises:

```
exercises: {
  push: ['Push up', 'Bench press'],
  legs: ['Squat', 'Power squats'],
  pull: ['Pull up', 'Chin up'],
  cardioCore: ['Running high knees', 'Plank']
}
```

How can I combine all of these into a single array or object? I need to create this:

```
allExercises: ['Push up', 'Bench press', 'Squat', 'Power squats', 'Pull up', 'Chin up', 'Running high knees', 'Plank']
```

I'm also going to sort alphabetically so the order isn't important.

I think I could do this with a `forEach`, something like this:

```
let allExercises = [];
exercises.forEach(exerciseGroup=>{
  allExercises.push(exerciseGroup);
});
```

But this feels a bit messy. Is there a nicer ES6 solution?

Comment: Use `.concat()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
const allExercises = Object.values(exercises)
  .reduce((array, subarray) => array.concat(subarray), []);
```

Comment: Personal preference, but instead of `.concat` function, one can also use the `...` (spread) operator

Comment: Also, is `Object.values` part of ES6 or ES7, just curious

Comment: @AyushGupta Hm… it’s actually ES8, but it can easily be polyfilled or replaced by a `Object.keys` approach.

Comment: Yeah, was just curious because this call once failed in `node 6.10` xD

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, ES6 compatible.:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(exercises)
.reduce((allExercises, exerciseName) => [...allExercises, ...(exercises[exerciseName])], [])
```

As @stealththeninja said, you can also do this to reduce a bunch of overhead.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(exercises).reduce((allExercises, exerciseName) => {
  allExercises.push(...exercises[exerciseName]);
  return allExercises;
}, []);
```

Comment: `[...all, ...exercises[name]` returns a new array each time. Reduce passes the object (or array) by reference, why not add the items and return `all`? `all.push(...exercises[name]); return all;`

Comment: You could, I just prefer the spread approach. One liner returns seem cleaner.

Comment: `One liner returns seem cleaner.` Cleaner syntactically but wasteful creating a new array for each property name.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. Edited the answer to add your suggestion as an alternative, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for considering the feedback, I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[].concat.apply([], Object.values(exercises));
```

Comment: What's the need for `.join(',').split(',')`?

Comment: `.join` joins nested arrays as if they are flat. `[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], 5].join(',')` will yeild `1,2,3,2,3,4,5`

Comment: @Xufox yes won't work if there is a comma in the exercise

Comment: Xufox raises a valid test case where the join/split fails. We might use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (`...`) but it's still unnecessarily more complex than using Object#values and Array#reduce.

Comment: That last approach is actually really elegant.

Comment: Agreed, nice edit. I would gladly undo my downvote except the original suggestion to use join/split was left in the answer.

Comment: Edited my answer, It has no `,` fault in it

Answer (score 0):

My ugly solution:

```
  let combineExercises = [];

  Object.values(allExercises).forEach((exerciseGroup) => {
    exerciseGroup.forEach((exercise) => {
      combineExercises.push(exercise)
    })
  });

  console.log(combineExercises);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` & `spread operator`

```js
var exercises = {
    push: ['Push up', 'Bench press'],
    legs: ['Squat', 'Power squats'],
    pull: ['Pull up', 'Chin up'],
    cardioCore: ['Running high knees', 'Plank']
}
var allexercise ={},tempArray=[];
for(var keys in exercises){

    tempArray.push(...Object.values(exercises[keys]))
}
allexercise=tempArray;

console.log(allexercise)
```